# Can we be able to convert meeting mode back to peer-to-peer call in MS Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams, botframework

Use case: When a PSTN number makes a call to calling Bot resource account, Bot answers the call. Now here is two participants and the call is **peer-to-peer** call

1. Phone (PSTN number)
2. Bot

And then we invite a new MS teams users to the call. Either the user rejects the call or timeout happens, once we hit the API [InviteParticipants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/participant-invite?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp), the call is converted to **meetingmode**

And we can not use [Transfer API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-transfer?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http), to transfer the call in meeting mode.

So I want to know if there is a way to convert the meetingmode call back to peer-to-peer call OR use transfer API in meeting mode?

Comment: Yes you cant use Transfer API to transfer the call in meeting mode. Need to see if other way exists for your scenario.

Comment: Yes I know that. But I want to know if there is any way to transfer the call to a user without using Invite API i.e. adding a transferee and removing the transferor. For details:
Please have look at this GitHub issue:
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/issues/395

Answer (score -1):

Currently, there is no API which can convert the meeting to peer-to-peer call

You can raise a [user voice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public-preview/category/182881-developer-platform).

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. It is not about the attendee list.
Please follow this link to more details on this issue.
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/issues/395